# Add a texture (with normal map) to a part of a "complex" object

Tags: texturing, normal-map

I would like to set a texture (with a normal map) only on the floor of my model. I created a material and assigned it to the selected faces :

[image: Selected faces]

Here are my material nodes :

[image: Material nodes]

The result :

[image: Result]

You can see my texture on the bottom of the picture but I would like to have my texture everywhere on the floor. Does someone have an idea ?

Here you can download the texture I use : [White Marble Square Tiles](https://www.textures.com/download/pbr0529/138564?q=wall)

Comment: Create the UV projection for the floor by Projecting from View from Top View, and then reference that UV map in the Normal Map node - and then also set up a Mapping node before the textures to control the scale of the mapping. Best to also set a Texture Mapping node using UV to the start there.